# Does TFS Backup include git repositories

Tags: tfs

Do TFS integrated Scheduled Backups include git repositories? I searched some, but couldn't find where they might be stored on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does.  Git repositories (just like TFVC repositories) are stored in the SQL Database that is included in the TFS Backups.

Comment: Do you maybe have some authoritative reference for this?